# Moodle Atto 'plugin not found'

Tags: yui, moodle

I've been trying to use the Atto plugin template (https://github.com/justinhunt/moodle-atto_newtemplate) to try and create my own Atto plugin. I've made the changes outlined in the README, and got shifter to run via npm. It appears to generate the build folder that matches the other plugins.

I'm able to see the plugin in configuration, and it's showing up in the Atto Toolbar Settings, but, when I pop open a text editor, I don't get an icon, and the console logs `moodle-editor_atto-editor: Plugin 'testplugin' could not be found - skipping initialisation`

I've found a few references in the docs that shifter is no longer used, and grunt is the new way to go, but I can't find any actual docs on this, and no gruntfile seems to exist anywhere.

Has anyone come across this before? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run shifter on your YUI code for it to work - the usual way of doing that, for Moodle 2.9 and above is to use grunt - see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Grunt for more details.

Comment: That's the odd thing. I did run shifter. It created build/moodle-atto_testplugin with 3 js files, but still doesn't show.

Comment: Looking at the other plugins in core, I'd expect there to be lib/editor/atto/plugins/testplugin/yui/src/button/ (with the js/ and meta/ subdirectories + build.json file). I'd then expect lib/editor/atto/plugins/testplugin/yui/build/moodle-atto_testplugin-button/ with the 3 js files in it. Try renaming the italic button (one of the simplest) and seeing if you can get that working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was ever resolved. The template is really helpful and it also comes with `lib`, `db`, and `version` PHP scripts. The string that you use as the plugin name has to be consistent throughout these scripts, as well as in your JS file. By default, it is set to `atto_NEWTEMPLATE`. Did you perhaps change this string to `atto_testplugin` in one place but not in all the others?